# При использовании макбука и его простое всплывают окна "Не удается найти файл"

Tags: macos, zoom

Без какой-либо видимой причины всплывают окна "Не удается найти файл" с иконкой файндера.
Версия мак ос - Big sur 11.3.1 (20E241).
Возможно, есть способ через strace / аналоги отследить причину появления этих окон?

**upd**

Методом проб и ошибок выяснил, что на 99% это связано с сочетанием zoom и приложения xpression camera - после удаления второго начинает появляться ошибка.
Так же после удаления xpression camera в зуме все равно остается возможность выбрать в качестве источника видео xpression camera.
Как удалить его полностью пока не понял.

Comment: Может вот это ваш случай? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252046791

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja сам вид ошибки - такой же, но происходит без подключения устройств к компьютеру

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил:
удалил xpression камера стандартными средствами, запустил system_profiler, он ругнулся:

```
 Error loading /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/XpressionPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/XpressionPlugin:  dlopen(/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/XpressionPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/XpressionPlugin, 0x0106): code signature in (/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/XpressionPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/XpressionPlugin) not valid for use in process: mapping process is a platform binary, but mapped file is not
```

После ручного удаления XpressionPlugin.plugin устройство пропало из списка источников и ошибка перестала появляться.